# How to use Custom Renderer in Xamarin Shared Project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, shared-project

I am using **Shared Project** for my cross platform mobile application and want to use **Custom renderer** in my app for native support.  Is there any way i can use Custom renderer in my app.

Comment: What makes you think it will not work or work any different from a PCL?

Comment: @Gerald : I was having one error "not found in assembly " so I changed the assembly name for iOS and Droid and it works .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in-between using custom renders in a PCL or Shared Project as seen [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/building_cross_platform_applications/sharing_code_options/). You still have a project per platform. That doesn't change. The real advantage is that you can use `ifdefs` when compared to PCLs.

[here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/) is all the information you'll need in regards to implementing custom renders. And [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/entry/) is an example of a custom renderer for an `Entry`.

Comment: "The real advantage is that you can use ifdefs when compared to PCLs." Or disadvantage, depending on your coding style :)

Comment: True enough, @FelipeLavratti :)

Comment: @Demitrian: Thanks ..it helps me to solve my problem.

Comment: You are welcome @sanjeev1988. Don't forget to vote and accept if you found the answer you were looking for :) That would help me as well

Comment: How do I get Control reference inside the ifdef? assuming am already inside Element of custom renderer.

Answer (score 1):

For Xamarin shared base project we have to set local in xmlns below format

**xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sampleforms"**

For Xamarin PCL base project we have to set local in xmlns below format

**xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sampleforms;assembly=Sampleforms"**

Reming everything will be same as what do for custom render.